# How to annotate ggplot2 qplot outside of legend and plotarea? (similar to mtext())

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate, r-grid

I would like to annotate my plots with a filename. With `plot()` I used `mtext`:

```
plot(1:10)
mtext("File xy-12-34-56.csv", 4)
```

How can I do that with ggplot2 and qplot or ggplot? It should not collide with the legend.
I found the commands `annotate` and `grid`, but I could not get an annotation similar to `mtext` with these.

As a workaround I could try [watermarks](http://blog.ggplot2.org/post/23537012922/adding-watermarks-to-plots), but perhaps you have a good hint for me. 
Kind regards, Jonas

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**

Looks like to achieve the result now we should use the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
p <- qplot(data = mtcars, wt, mpg)
grid.arrange(p, right = textGrob("File xy-12-34-56.csv", rot = -90, vjust = 1))
```

**Old answer**

Try this:

```
library(gridExtra)
p <- qplot(data = mtcars, wt, mpg)
print(arrangeGrob(p, legend = textGrob("File xy-12-34-56.csv", rot = -90, vjust = 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Does this require a call to grid? `library(grid)`?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen, thanks for reminding, that is actually `gridExtra`

Comment: @jbaums, you are right. I have just updated the answer.