# add banner to bottom of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to add a banner to the bottom of a ggplot? For example,

Turn this:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + stat_density(aes(x = mpg))
```

[image]

Into this:

[image]

Comment: Possibly this post gives you a direction to look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009135/how-to-annotate-ggplot2-qplot-outside-of-legend-and-plotarea-similar-to-mtext

Comment: There's nothing in ggplot specifically for this, but ggplot is build on the grid package. You can look into mucking about with grid viewports to add any content you want to the graphics device.

Comment: You might take guidance from [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644728/add-image-png-file-to-header-of-pdf-file-created-with-r/26851776#26851776) using `gtable` or [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463691/inserting-an-image-to-ggplot-outside-the-chart-area/12486301#12486301) using `grid`.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate necessarily. Two things: as of ggplot 2.1.0.9000 (dev version, as of this comment), you can subtitles and captions to plots via `+labs(title="Title",subtitle="A subtitle",caption="Source of data...")`. Also, I posted a question about a function I created to add a ribbon to the bottom of a plot. It's not perfect but it might help: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071468/add-info-ribbon-flush-to-bottom-of-ggplot?noredirect=1#comment59789368_36071468)