# Add info ribbon flush to bottom of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a programmatic way of adding a ribbon at the bottom of my ggplot2 plots like Fivethirtyeight does. Their plots usually have their logo and source information at the bottom inside the ribbon, e.g.:

[image: (https://espnfivethirtyeight.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/hickey-goodman-1.png?w=575&h=462)]

Here's my addBanner function. It works, except when faceting plots, especially with coord_map, the banner ends up wider than the plot:

[image]

```
addBanner<-function(plot, lefttext=NULL, righttext=NULL, plotHeight=20, textsize=10, bannercolor="grey",textcolor="white"){
  # Create grobs to add to plot
  my_g <- 
    grobTree(rectGrob(gp=gpar(alpha=1
                              ,fill = bannercolor
                              , col = bannercolor
                              #,fill="#b82e3e" #red
                              #,col= "#b82e3e" #red
                              #,fill="#999999" #grey
                              #,col= "#999999" #grey
    )
    )
    , textGrob(lefttext, x=0, hjust=0, gp=gpar(col=textcolor
                                               ,fontfamily = "Helvetica"
                                               ,fontsize = textsize
                                               ,fontface="bold"))
    ,textGrob(righttext, x=1, hjust=1, gp=gpar(col=textcolor
                                               ,fontfamily = "Helvetica"
                                               ,fontsize = textsize
                                               ,fontface="bold")
    )
    )

  gA <- plot
  # Add as a strip along bottom
  grid.arrange(gA,my_g, heights=c(plotHeight, 1))

}

# TESTING
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

crimes <- data.frame(state = tolower(rownames(USArrests)), USArrests)
crimesm <- reshape2::melt(crimes, id = 1)
states_map <- map_data("state")

testPlot<-
    ggplot(crimesm, aes(map_id = state)) +
    geom_map(aes(fill = value), map = states_map) +
    coord_map()+
    expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat) +
    facet_wrap( ~ variable)
addBanner(testPlot,lefttext="   Company Name",righttext="Source of Data   ",textcolor="white")
```

Comment: This has to do with the ratio at which you render the plot. You could, e.g., open it with Zoom in RStudio and play with the ratio to see how the relative width of bar and plot change.

Comment: I think what I need is a way to set the width of the banner equal to the width of the faceted plot?