# Add a stat table to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add to ggplot (PLOT) graph a table reporting the significance of the analysis of variance:

```
aov2<-aov(Ce~O+H+O:H, data=df)
mytable<-summary(aov2)
```

I have tried:

```
PLOT+
mtext(mytable)
Error in mtext(mytable) : plot.new has not been called yet
```

Comment: mtext does not work with `ggplot2` plots, only with base. See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009135/how-to-annotate-ggplot2-qplot-outside-of-legend-and-plotarea-similar-to-mtext) for the ggplot equivalent

Comment: Also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409960/ggplot2-annotate-outside-of-plot)

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318120/adding-table-within-the-plotting-region-of-a-ggplot-in-r) seems the most on point

Comment: @user295691 this is actually very close to my point, but it requires to build the table manually in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questions linked show how to add a table to a plot, but in order to produce that, you need a table to start with.

To get a table from the summary object, you need to extract the actual table from the summary.

```
mytable <- summary(aov2)[[1]]
```

will do the trick.