# ggplot2 add text in the legend area

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny

I would like to add some totals on the right side of the plot (above and under the legend). And also under the title of the x axis.

I found how to add text within the plot, or add multiple legends of something ploted, but I don't want to do either one. I just want to calculate some totals and display them as mentioned above. Is it in any way possible?

As it is now:
[image]

As I would like it to be:
[image]

Comment: Look into cowplot package. There is `draw_label` function that helps to put text anywhere on the plot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to annotate ggplot2 qplot outside of legend and plotarea? (similar to mtext())](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009135/how-to-annotate-ggplot2-qplot-outside-of-legend-and-plotarea-similar-to-mtext)

Comment: You could use shiny to add text under the x-axis,but I don't see how you can expect to add something above and/or under the legend without modifying the plot. Shiny has no idea where the legend is, it is just a bitmap for Shiny.

Comment: from cowplot:
ggdraw(p) +
  draw_label("bottom left at (0, 0)", x = 0, y = 0, hjust = 0, vjust = 0)